# selecting ul elements by number of li children

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

hallo all. i am trieng to build a function that gets all ul's on screen that have less then 3 li elements.
i need this as a jquery object. so i dont mind if it will be a function or just one selector.

how do i do it?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) for this, for example:

```
$("ul").filter(function() { return $(this).children().length<3; }).doSomething();
```

With this we're getting all `<ul>` elements, then filtering down to *only* those who have fewer than 3 children, by checking the [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) of [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).

Comment: i dare to give alternative answer in front of Nick :)

Comment: @JapanPro - alternatives are the spice of life, always post em of you got em.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work:

```
$('ul:not(:contains(li:eq(2)))')
```

Comment: `:contains()` is a text selector, you probably wanted `:has()` here, but that'd still give false positives with nested lists.